# How to filter all words with the letter e into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am trying to put all the words that have the letter e in a separate array yet I can not figure out how to input a variable into the Regular Expression.

I have already tried plugging a variable into a metacharacter of regex.

```
var inputletter = "e"

startlist = ["jambee", "dangen", "oragna", "sabotta"];
filter1 = [];
var regex = new RegExp(startlist, "g");

for (var i = 0; i < startlist.length; i++) {
  if(regex.test(regex, "regex") == true) {
    filter1.push(startlist[i])

  }

};
   console.log(filter1);
```

Comment: 1. RegExp receive a pattern when declaring but you assign it with object that is going to test and remove the "g". Change to new RegExp(inpuletter);
2. regex.test accept the object to check for pattern declared above, so you should pass in startlist[i] as the object to be tested. 

e.g.:
if (regex.test(startlist[i])) {
  filter1.push(startlist[i]);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use array filter function and also use `includes` to check if the word contains the character

```js
var inputletter = "e"

startlist = ["jambee", "dangen", "oragna", "sabotta"];

function filter1(arr, char) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.includes(char)
  })


}
console.log(filter1(startlist, inputletter));
```

Comment: This did not only help me, but it changed my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are using test wrong:

```
let regex = new RegExp("e");

...

if(regex.test(startlist[i])) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind moving away from using a regex, you can use Javascript's [array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [string.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and the [string.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) methods to create an array where each element has at least one 'e'

```js
let startlist = ["jambee", "dangen", "oragna", "sabotta"];
let result = startlist.filter((element) => element.toLowerCase().includes('e'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: he can still use a regular expression element => regexp.test(element)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your existing code you simply need to test the letter (the regex consisting of just that letter) against each element in the array (`startlist[i]`).

```js
const startlist = ['jambee', 'dangen', 'oragna', 'sabotta'];
const filter1 = [];
const regex = /e/;

for (var i = 0; i < startlist.length; i++) {
  const word = startlist[i];
  if (regex.test(word)) filter1.push(word);
};

console.log(filter1);
```

Alternatively you can use a slightly more functional method using the array [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, and the string [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method

```js
const startlist = ["jambee", "dangen", "oragna", "sabotta"];

const filtered = startlist.filter(word => {
  return word.includes('e');
});

console.log(filtered);
```